# C# - Read delimited text file that contains extra delimiter in rows

Tags: c#, excel, datatable, textfieldparser

I am importing an excel file into DataTable and generating a '~' delimited file text using C#.

And importing the delimited file into DataTable to validate the data.

My Code:

```
DataTable data = new DataTable()
using(TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser(filePath))
{
     parser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;
     parser.SetDelimiters("~");

     while (!parser.EndOfData)
     {
          if(data.Columns.Count == 0)
          {              
              foreach (string field in parser.ReadFields())
                     data.Columns.Add(field, typeof(string));
          }
          else
          {
               data.Rows.Add(parser.ReadFields());
          }  
     } 
     data.AccepChanges();
```

If the delimited file contains an extra delimiter '~' in the data, (2nd row in this example)

For eg: if the excel file contains this data:

```
Account    Name      Age
1000       John      20
2000       ~Doe      23
3000       Jason     25
```

The delimited file generated is this:

```
Account~Name~Age
1000~John~20
2000~~Doe~23
3000~Jason~25
```

it is giving an exception when adding the row to datatable:

```
"Input array is longer than the number of columns in this table"
```

How do I read the file that contains extra delimiter in the data?

Comment: Can you not change your delimiter to something like a comma? Also should Doe retain the extra '~' or should it be dropped to look like 2000~Doe~23

Comment: @mathis1337 - No, this is just an example of the data. The actual data (5 million rows) which is coming from the client contains a lot of other characters like "comma, \, /, " etc. We are using '~' as it might rarely occur in the data.

Comment: @mathis1337  - Doe should retain the extra '~'

Comment: Since you have so many records just make your delimiter more complex. Do something like'~*^',  The likely hood of that occurring is probably less. You can of course add more if needed. I will provide an answer down below

Comment: This interview question is intended to a) have discussion on why using standard data formats is important, and b) demonstrate good understanding of  backtracking algorithms to find best possible option to parse such string. I don't think this is applicable to real world applications so do not expect standard parser will try to pick the best option (generally non-deterministic) when parsing CSV.

Comment: `HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true` means what it says: you must escape the delimiter using quotes. Your so-called CSV does not have that for some reason, which leads me to believe it wasn't generated in Excel

Answer (score 0):

Here just use a more complex delimiter to avoid any collisions with text since records are large.

```
using (TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser("D:/test.txt"))
{
    parser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;
    parser.SetDelimiters("~*^");
    
    string[] fields;
    
    while (!parser.EndOfData)
    {
        fields = parser.ReadFields();
        foreach (string field in fields)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(field);
        }
    }
}
```

This outputs:

[image]

As you can see it keeps the '~Doe' and separates just fine.

This is what the txt file had: `2000~*^~Doe~*^23`

Comment: This should require you to just change delimiter too and not anymore code.

Comment: Yes, that should work fine. But will have to check with the Client, since they have an application where they input the delimited text file into their application to read the file data.

Comment: Yeah  I mean normalizing your data is rather important, if you can't then you should at least make the delimiter rather unique and not just one character. If not you will have to basically scan each character, and if you detect the delimiter, and then another delimiter x  infinity to skip x amount of times and move on. Don't think the parser toolkit you are using can do that. Perhaps a regex could. That our put your ~Doe in quotes. If you put it in quotes you can easily use regex. Let me know if that is possible. I can show a regex solution for that.